# Extract data from multiple objects with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

Hello I want to extract data from an Object and store them into an array.

In my case i want to extract all the us shoe sizes and want to put them in an array.

When using the filter method it only spits out the first one that has the "us": value in it

```
{
    us: '5.5',
    eur: '38',
    uk: '5',
    cm: '24',
  },
  {
    us: '6',
    eur: '38.5',
    uk: '5.5',
    cm: '24',
  },
  {
    us: '6.5',
    eur: '39',
    uk: '6',
    cm: '24.5',
  },
  {
    us: '7',
    eur: '40',
    uk: '6',
    cm: '25',
  },
  {
    us: '7.5',
    eur: '40.5',
    uk: '6.5',
    cm: '25.5',
  },
  {
    us: '8',
    eur: '41',
    uk: '7',
    cm: '26',
  },
  {
    us: '8.5',
    eur: '42',
    uk: '7.5',
    cm: '26.5',
  },
```

Comment: What  have you tried so far?

Comment: use map instead of filter you migh want to combine them(map and filter) only if you want to exclude objects(not containing us for example)

Answer (score 1):

You can use map here assuming your objects are stored in an array.

```
const result = objecs.map(x => x.us);
```

This will create a new array result where only your objects us property values are stored in.

```
[
  "5.5",
  "6",
  "6.5",
  "7",
  "7.5",
  "8",
  "8.5"
]
```

```js
const objecs = [{
  us: '5.5',
  eur: '38',
  uk: '5',
  cm: '24',
}, {
  us: '6',
  eur: '38.5',
  uk: '5.5',
  cm: '24',
}, {
  us: '6.5',
  eur: '39',
  uk: '6',
  cm: '24.5',
}, {
  us: '7',
  eur: '40',
  uk: '6',
  cm: '25',
}, {
  us: '7.5',
  eur: '40.5',
  uk: '6.5',
  cm: '25.5',
}, {
  us: '8',
  eur: '41',
  uk: '7',
  cm: '26',
}, {
  us: '8.5',
  eur: '42',
  uk: '7.5',
  cm: '26.5',
}]


const result = objecs.map(x => x.us);
console.log(result);
```